# Alternatives for languages that ad sense doesn't support

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

**Introduction:**

I am working with my local website which displays local contents in local language.

**Problem:**

Unfortunately my local language not supported by the Google Ads as per:

[image]

So one way I thought was to convert all text/string into image and display images instead.(Server Side)

**Question**

I am using c# method to convert text to image. I dont understand its **implementation for multi-line text?**

Or is there a better way to support languages that ad sense doesn't support without images?

**C# Code**

```
            string text = str.Trim();
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
            int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Height;
            bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(width, height));
            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)), 0, 0);
            graphics.Flush();
            graphics.Dispose();
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()) + ".jpg";
            bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Images/") +"11"+fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //imgText.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + fileName;
            //imgText.Visible = true;
            return "~/App_Images/My_Converted.jpg";
```

If someone have any idea about this type of problem or any refrence/link, please do help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What language? Surely Google would have this covered...  Why would you show google ads as images? you probably won't be paid if you do that, so it makes no sense, plus there are so many ads. To answer your question you can do 2 or more DrawString calls for multi-line, Google: Msdn DrawString

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thanks for reply, i meant my website contents are in local language which is not supported by google adsense.So what i figured is that i can show images of that content written in local language .....

Comment: @DownVoter Care to explain the nature of his downvote action ?????So i can edit my question accordingly !!!!

Comment: Ok I see. There has to be a better way, I googled and see the dilemma (I didn't down vote)

Comment: @JeremyThompson please post it as answer.Its a good direction if i look for builtin draw method to do that .....Dear i know, usually downvoters dont comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can simply put a newline (\r\n) in the string.

---

I edited your question to be more appealing and relevant to a wider audience. Please leave this question unmarked for a while to hear some more ideas, cheers!

Comment: Great Many Thanks, +1 for help

Comment: @"You're \r\n Welcome";